# How to get all the item of a jstl select in MVC Spring controller from view

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, jstl

I am using Spring MVC and JSTL tag for jsp pages as frontend ...
I have a jstl select option in view ... the select is populated from db ....now I want that if I press a submit butten ... I can get all the item of the list box back to the Spring MVC controller.. How can I do this ???

Here is my JSTL Select box :-

```
<form:select id="upperTier" path="propertyCode" cssClass="textfield">
<c:if test="${upperTyrePropertyCodeList!=null}">
<form:options items="${upperTyrePropertyCodeList}" itemValue="propertyCode" itemLabel="propertyCode" />
</c:if>
</form:select>
```

Now I want all the items of select box (upperTyrePropertyCodeList) back to the controller ... not any select ted index ....

Comment: upperTyrePropertyCodeList was populated by server itself right. SO you already would have access to service classes which got the data in first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to all upperTyrePropertyCodeList back to you submit action,you can do like this:

```
<c:forEach var="index" items="${upperTyrePropertyCodeList}">    
  <form:hidden name="propertyCode" value="${index.propertyCode}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

select box  only hold the selected value to controller.